# What's the recommended way to join data between partitions on Service Fabric?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

We store our data in `IReliableDictionary` on the Service Fabric. Let's say we have a Service running on Partition A, that want to get data that is stored on Partition B - What's the best way to do this?

Are you supposed to do a HTTP or Web Socket call to the second Partition? Would be great if someone could link some documentation or examples on this topic. If you post code, please explain the idea behind it.

Azure Service Fabric Documentation do not seem to cover it in detail from what I can find.

Comment: Could you please explain why you need to access data in Partition B from Partition A within the same service?

Comment: So let's say Player A is in Partition A and we want to calculate a match against Player B that happens to be in Partition B. For the MatchService that calculate the result of the match, it will need to access user-data from multiple different partitions.

Comment: There is an idea to store data as close as possible to calculation to reduce transmission time. If you will follow this idea, then you have to store info about players in one partition. For example, if you information required for calculation is not so large, then you can have a separate service that in some periods of time will collect data from all the partitions and then you can perform calculations in one partition of that service. If this idea does not fit into your requirements, then you can just make a call to the same service, but specifying another partition within the same service.

Comment: Yes I already figured out that I could do multiple calls to the same service, but that didn't feel like a "good" way to do it. I thought there would be some built in functionality, or "official" way to collect data between Partitions.

Could it be that Service Fabric Stateful Services are not really meant to work in the way I want it to? Should I look for other solutions such as SQL databases if I need to collect data from multiple Partitions like this?

Comment: If you don't like the idea with a collector that will collect all the required (and only required) data from all partitions (and store it only in memory) for the task, then, probably, you could store everything in only one partition. Partitions are useful for storing separately huge amount of data. Have you tried to store everything in only one partition and measure performance? Otherwise, yes, you should try another solution because all advantages of partitioning will be lost because of crosspartition communication.

Comment: @MarcusLind Could you change your partitioning scheme so that it partitions based on the match and not based on the player. That way the data for both players is stored in the same partition?

Comment: @Dismissile Well problem is that if we have 1,000,000 players, and every player have a few matches every single day, then there will be a lot of matches between a lot of different players. So even though some might be stored in the same partition, there will always be a chance that a player will play against a player in another partition.

Comment: @MarcusLind It sounds like the data should be coming from another service then, not another partition in the same service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your trying to apply some kind of relational pattern onto dictionaries across partitions.  This is not really ideal.  You would not do that with normal dictionaries either.  In general, if you taking a dependency on specific partitions or prior knowledge of partitions, it is a big hint your model is probably wrong.  Dictionaries are great for finding one thing by key very quickly, not for doing 1-to-many and not good to enumerate over the whole thing either.  The serializable object you store can contain all your data including the *many lists. Up to a point, if you storing 100s of thousands of rows in a child collection in the object, then probably not right either.